# Maui Detail View Control - Tabs? Carousel?

Tags: xamarin, maui

What is the recommended way to show detail content in Maui. The app is a port from Xamarin where TabbedPage was used to show lots of item data. This does not work with shell navigation. Not using shell navigation is also proving problematic.
Ideally this method would be able to load content from other ContentPages and provide a way to move between them while not moving from the container page.
Any help appreciated.

Comment: this is really vague, and asking for opinions.  I would generally not use a tab control to show detail view, so I'm not quite sure what your use case is

Comment: Sorry for the vagueness Jason. I'm new to Maui and it looks like there isn't an off the shelf way to show lots of detail, using Content pages and a Container page without a coding effort. TabbedPage and CarouselPage appear not to be options. And TabBar is for navigation. The question is very high level, as I'm new to Maui, I feel I'm missing something basic. What is the GUI approach to show lots of detail, similiar to Tabs in Jquery or Windows Tabs etc.

Comment: however you did it in Xamarin should work in MAUI.  Please **show** us what your solution was, don't just describe it